# Retrieving data based on several conditions in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using AJAX to get database data, compare it to a variable to display it. I'm only comparing in "Where" based on one condition, which is whether the field ID is equal to a variable "+id_var +". The thing is that now i'm trying to add more conditions in Where for different fields, but i'm not being successful, any help on how to do so?

```
 var key=null;
 $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "GetRecord?DB=EMP&Table=EMP_HISTORY",
                   dataType : 'xml',
                   data : {
                    "Where" : "ID="+id_var +""  
                   },
                 success:function(xml) {
                     $(xml).find('record').each(function () {
                        key = $(this).find("KEY").text();
                     });
                     if(key) {
                        var url = "GetDisplay?DB=EMP&Table=EMP_HISTORY&Where=KEY="+key +"";
                        window.open(url,"_self");
                     }
                 },
                 error: function (error) {
                     alert('error');
                 }
               });
```

Comment: please show all the conditions you would like to add

Comment: @nosthertus i'm just looking for syntax, but let's the say the above condition with " OR "+id_var +" IS NULL "

Answer (score 0):

i can see you have an error in your `HTTP Query`, you can't define `where` a value which is defining `key` another value inside.. for this you would have to change `Where` to be an array which would contain `KEY` and other variables you want it to have..

Assuming you are using `jQuery`.. you can use `$.param()`, check in [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) for more details..

```
var query = {
    DB: "EMP",
    Table: "EMP_HISTORY",
    Where: {
        KEY: "1234",
        OR: {
            id_var: 'IS NULL'

        }
    }
};

$.param(query);

// returns "DB=EMP&Table=EMP_HISTORY&Where%5BKEY%5D=1234&Where%5BOR%5D%5Bid_var%5D=IS+NULL"
```